# Importando o conteúdo de uma div de um site para dentro da minha aplicação

Tags: html, android

Bom quero pegar o conteúdo de uma "div" de um site para exibir-lo na minha aplicação, já vi algo sobre WebView, mas não faço ideia de como fazer...

Comment: já tentou jquery? Nele existe formas de você capturar o conteúdo de um elemento por um id e depois basta colocar este conteúdo no local que você deseja com o próprio jquery.

Comment: ja procurei e não consegui achar do jeito que quero fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a lib [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) para isso. Um exemplo do seu seria:

Classe MainActivity

```
TextView txv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

    new RequestTask().execute("http://sites.ecomp.uefs.br/perta/");
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        String text = null;
        try {
            // pega o codigo html de um site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri[0]).get();
            // pega um elemento do codigo
            Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#sites-header-title");
            // pega o texto dentro do codigo
            text = newsHeadlines.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null){
            txv.setText(result);
        }else{
            txv.setText("FALHA!");
        }
    }
}
```

Coloque a permissão para acesso à internet

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Com isso eu pego o texto dentro de  com id #sites-header-title e coloco dentro de um TextView

Comment: como vou inserir a library jsoup-1.7.3.jar ao meu projeto?

Comment: baixe o arquivo jar e coloque dentro da pasta lib no seu projeto.

Comment: fiz exatamente como vc me mando pra ver se funciona, mas deu erro.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/XEprrd4S

Comment: Deve ser a permissão de internet, atualizei o post

Comment: Pensei que era isso também mais não é, ja esta com permissão.

Comment: Agora descobri, tava tentando rodar em 2.2, tentei em 4.2 e funcionou, só que tem que ser compatível :(

Comment: pow serio que não tem como rodar em 2.2 pra cima? :(